# In the Eclipse PDT, is it possible to configure content assist to look for alternative tags to suggest PHP types?

Tags: php, eclipse, phpdoc, eclipse-pdt, content-assist

I'm working on a project that uses the Lithium (http://li3.me/) framework and they document their classes like this:

```
class Controller extends \lithium\core\Object {

    /**
     * Contains an instance of the `Request` object with all the details of the HTTP request that
     * was dispatched to the controller object. Any parameters captured in routing, such as
     * controller or action name are accessible as properties of this object, i.e.
     * `$this->request->controller` or `$this->request->action`.
     *
     * @see lithium\action\Request
     * @var object
     */
    public $request = null;
```

I've always used fully qualified class names in the @var and Eclipse seems to do a good job with that for generating content assist.  However they seem to document class names using @see tags instead, and content assist is not available.  Is there a way to configure PDT to use the information in the @see tag as a class name for the purposes of content assist?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible without own plugin. @see tag should be used for links only.